# Laravel custom validation message for multiple fields with the same name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have the following validation in the controller's action:

```
foreach ($request['qtys'] as $key => $val){
            if (!$this->_validateMinQty($key, $job, $val)){
                $customerTitle = $job->customers()->where('customer_id',$key)->first()->title;
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['qtys' => __('The qty of the customer :customerTitle is less than allowed qty',['customerTitle' => $customerTitle])]);
            }
        }
```

This check multiple form's input named `qtys` in the view:

```
@foreach($job->customers as $customer)

    <div class="form-group {{$errors->first('qtys has-error')}}">
        {!! Form::label('qtys-'.$customer->id, __('Qty').' '.$customer->title) !!}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {!! Form::text('qtys['.$customer->id.']',$customer->pivot->e_production,['class' =>'form-control qtys', "data-sumequal"=>"qty",'required' => 'required','title' => $customer->pivot->aid,'id' => 'qtys-'.$customer->id]) !!}
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                 @php ($eleE =  $errors->first('qtys'))
                @include('layouts.form-ele-error')
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="/storage/create/{{$customer->pivot->aid}}" class="btn btn-nile"><i class="fox-add"></i>{{__('Add Storage')}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    @endforeach
```

The above code works, but with the following limitation:

The error message is rendered under every input named `qtys[x]` where x is an integer and the first input only `Testana` has the invalid qty, like the following screen shot: 
[image]

In the controller's action return message, I have tried to use indexed name for the input like the following:

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['qtys.10' => ....
```

However, it prevents rendering the error message under any `qtys` field. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I have found starts from the [definition of first method](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html) found in the view :

```
@php ($eleE =  $errors->first('qtys'))
```

This, in my code, should be changed to:

```
@php ($eleE =  $errors->first('qtys.'.$customer->id))
```

Because the multiple fields have gotten keys equals to the customer id. *This is a technique I usually use, when I want to send double piece of data in single post or in single form element.* 
Then in the controller, I keep the first try,

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['qtys.'.$key => __('The qty of the customer :customerTitle is less than allowed qty',['customerTitle' => $customerTitle])]);
```

Where `$key` is an integer.